# Inline keyword gfortran

Tags: fortran, inline, gfortran

Is there any Fortran keyword equivalent to the C "inline" keyword?

If some compiler-specific keyword exist, is there any for gfortran?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the Fortran specifications grant the compiler writers enormous scope in how to implement things, so a language-level construct that forced (or even hinted) specific optimizations would be very un-Fortran-y.

What you typically do in modern Fortran is not specify optimizations, but tell the compiler things it can use to decide what optimizations to implement.  So an example is labelling a side-effect-free function or subroutine `PURE`, so that certain optimizations are enabled (and actually, this may make for easier inlining).

Otherwise, as @Vladimir F points out, you can use compiler options which *are* presecriptive in this way.

In a similar vein, it seems that `CONTAIN`ed subprogram are more aggressively inlined by gfortran, but that may or may not help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no source code statement I know of. Sometimes you can use statement functions, which are obviously inlined. Otherwise use compiler comand line options as gfortran's "-finline-functions".